# Run npm command during post deploy powershell step in Octopus

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm, octopus-deploy

I have a nodejs application that I've built/packaged via teamcity as well as deploy to one of our servers (which has node installed) through the Octopus deploy portal.
Everything works ok until i come to the post deploy powershell script from within octopus.

In one of the code blocks I have `npm commands` that throws an error `npm  not recognised`.When I run the power-shell scripts on the server, everything works but when I try to run this via the octopus post deploy script I get the error as stated above.

I know that node /npm are installed and that the environment variables re:nodejs is set correctly, unless there is something else i'm missing , it still isn't working.

a simple pseudo-code of what i'm trying to  do is this:

```
$deploymentDir = 'D:\Apps\<appname>\<octopus-version-number>' 
    $name = "service" 
    cd $deploymentDir
    if($name){
         Write-Host "link node-windows..."
         npm link node-windows //node-windows is installed globally



    }

else{

    }
```

Unless there  is something I'm missing , how can I get this to run via octopus ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility that **Octopus master/tentacle service** runs on **different user**, check the environment variable for that user also.

If you unable to find the root cause, the alternate is define one Target scoped variable called `"npmPath"` ( value may be different based on target ) in octopus to store npm path

Now, you can use `$npmPath` variable in script.

Comment: The first option: `change the user that the tentacle service runs on` worked for me. It was using `local user` previously.